# Problems with System File Checker (SFC)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I had once attempted to restyle my UI by installing some transformation packs. However, I later decided to uninstall them, and so I did.

Later on, I decided to install some programs, but the prerequisites were the .NET Frameworks 2, 3 and 3.5. Problem was that, I couldn't install them as they kept on rolling back. I searched online and decided to run System File Checker (SFC). However, SFC kept on giving me this error:

I suspect its something to do with my transformation pack, as I reviewed the logs and winload.exe, winload.exe.mui, winresume.exe, winresume.exe.mui were the 4 files reviewed in the logs. Refer to the log file here: http://www.4shared.com/office/xmAEMYq4/scannow.html

Later on, I ran "sfc /verifyonly" (without quotes) in CMD. I got this error:

```
    Windows Resource Protection found integrity violations. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.
```

Refer to the log file here: http://www.4shared.com/office/EK4rmQ9X/verifyonly.html

I checked C:\Windows\winsxs\Backup already, but I cannot find any backups of the 4 files. Is there any way I can fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Pro tip: Don't mess with SFC DLL cache

Comment: use a different file hoster or dropbox/skydrive. I don't register just to download a file.

Comment: @magicandre1981 sorry, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @ta.speot.is a little too late, eh.

Comment: where is the new link? Or are you no longer interested in a solution?

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25468623/verifyonly.txt and https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25468623/scannow.txt
thanks (: @magicandre1981

Comment: you have STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED errors while repairing the damaged files. Disable the realtime protection of your AV software and try again.

Comment: @magicandre1981 (sorry for the late reply) okay, i'll attempt it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 tried it, still won't go more than 10%. link:https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25468623/help.log

Comment: you still have the STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED errors. Do an inplace upgrade to repair Windows: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: ah well, I'll see how things go. Will it work for an OEM license?