# In-place upgrade: from Windows 7 to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I asked a question recently, and was suggested to do an in-place upgrade. Refer to link here: [Problems with System File Checker (SFC)](https://superuser.com/questions/541993/problems-with-system-file-checker-sfc).

While I understand **how** to do an in-place upgrade, I do have some queries.

- I'm using a laptop with an OEM license. With the in-place upgrade, will it nullify my license?

- Will the licenses of my other programs (e.g. Office 2010) be nullified too?

- What will be done to the computer (i.e. What folders will be tinkered with?)

Thank you.

Comment: It's actually a "repair install" and as long as you install the same version as you had it should work with your OEM license -- at least it did on my friend's machine that I just applied it to.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the clarification on the first point (:

Comment: Oops, forgot to also mention that your other program's licenses should be OK, too, afterwards. The main point of a repair install is to fix Windows by reinstalling it at the same time keeping the rest of your software intact. The main limitation, as I see it, is that your machine needs to a least be running well enough to start the installation process from the running OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On-place upgrade doesn't affect your files...it affect system files only.
but if you do not care about office and others you may need to make restore to defaults as follow:

A Lot of laptops recently come with hidden partition which contains like (Restore to factory defaults) which reinstall the fresh windows 7 that came with the laptop,with some bloatware you can remove it later.
To reach to this option you have to press a button for 3 to 5 seconds while power on the laptop (like my toshiba laptop i have to press 0 button and while this pressing i power on the laptop 0 button+power on at the same time) but your laptop may differ,then the hidden menu appear and restore to defaults.but do not return the disk to defaults as one partition and let your partitions without any change.
your files on c: partition may removed and other partitions will still without changes.
your windows licence not affected.
your other programs will affected.

Comment: I do know my computer has that feature, but was wondering if I could have no impact on my licensed files.